# Priority to the right

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to regulate traffic on a crossroads. There are 4 roads coming from north, east, south and west.

The input is a string representing the upcoming traffic on each road. For example, `NNNWS` indicates there is a total of 5 cars: three at the north, one at the west and one at the south. The order of characters has no importance here, `NNNWS` is equivalent to `WNNSN`.

You must output the order in which the cars should go, using the priority to the right rule: cars coming from the south must let cars coming from east go first, east gives way to north, north gives way to west and west gives way to south.

For example, with the input `NNNWS`, the south car should go first, then the west car, then the 3 north cars. The output should thus be `SWNNN`.

There are some indecidable cases, for example `NS` or `NNWSE` : you should then output the string `stuck`.

**Test cases**

```
N => N
NW => WN
NWS => SWN
SNW => SWN
SSSSS => SSSSS
ENNNNES => NNNNEES
NS => stuck
NNWSE => stuck
```

Comment: Both of those seem a lot harder because they take the outgoing directions into account as well.

Comment: I would recommend using undefined behavior instead of printing `stuck`.

Comment: @Erik when dealing with road safety, an undefined behavior cannot be accepted :-)

Comment: @Fatalize.  The "Solve a traffic intersection" challenge is far more demanding and intricate than the present challenge.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57043/solve-a-traffic-intersection). [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50436/schedule-a-4-way-stop).

Comment: @SuperChafouin So, code golfing is accepted, huh?

Comment: Is the empty string possible as input ? If so, what should the result be? And why is `NS` stuck ? Because both `NS` and `SN` would be a solution ?

Comment: can we stop the program/print nothing instead of printing `stuck`?

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 65 bytes

Includes +2 for `-lp`

Give input on STDIN. Assumes the empty string is not a valid input

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -lp
s%.%'+(y/NESW/ESWN/*s/N(.*)W/W$1N/,/N/^/S/)'x4%gere+0or$_=stuck
```

If you don't mind the absence of a newline after `stuck` you can drop the `l` option

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 267 Bytes

use the new [spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
-5 Bytes by @IsmaelMiguel

```
<?foreach($f=[E,S,W,N]as$l)$s.=+!($r=strstr)($i=$argv[1],$l);if(in_array($s,[0101,1010,0000]))die(stuck);$x=($p=strpos)($s,"1");$t=$r($j=join($f),$f[$x]).$r($j,$f[$x],1);$a=str_split($i);usort($a,function($x,$y)use($t,$p){return$p($t,$x)<=>$p($t,$y);});echo join($a);
```

### Breakdown

```
# Extended Version without notices
$s="";
foreach($f=["E","S","W","N"] as $l){$s.=+!strstr($i=$argv[1],$l);} #bool concat swap the false true values in string
if(in_array($s,["0101","1010","0000"])){die("stuck");} # NS WE NESW -> stuck = end program
$x=strpos($s,"1"); # find the first false value for an begin for the sort algorithm
$t=strstr($j=join($f),$f[$x]).strstr($j,$f[$x],1); # create the sort pattern
#sort algorithm example sort string = NESW-> N is not in the string
function c($x,$y){
    global $t;
    return strpos($t,$x)<=>strpos($t,$y); # e.g. comparison E<=>W =-1 , W<=>S=1, W<=>W =0
}
$a=str_split($i); # Input in an array
usort($a,"c"); #sort array
echo join($a);# output array as string
```

Comment: Instead of `function c($x,$y){global$t,$p;return$p($t,$x)<=>$p($t,$y);}$a=str_split($i);usort($a,c);`, you can use `$a=str_split($i);usort($a,function($x,$y)use($t,$p){return$p($t,$x)<=>$p($t,$y);});` and save 5 bytes. The spaceship operator really helped with this sort of sorting. For you to understand what I did, I moved the function into `usort()`, making it an anonymous function. Then, instead of `global` (NEVER use it), I've used `function(...)use($t,$p){...}`. The `use(...)` syntax allows you to pass variables into the anonymous function body (it accepts recerences too).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thank You for this wonderful explaining.

Comment: You're welcome. I really love the `use()` bit on anonymous functions. You should use and abuse it.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>108</s> <s>107</s> <s>106</s> 104 bytes

```
s=>(r=t=`NESWNE`,s.replace(/./g,c=>r|=2<<t.search(c)),t.substr(449778192>>r&3,1053417876>>r&3)||`stuck`)
```

Accumulates a bitmask of which directions have approaching cars and extracts the appropriate portion of the priority string.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /`

Comment: @Cyoce Whoops. What happened was that the browser wrapped the code at that point and I thought a newline had crept in. Sorry about that.

Comment: no problem, just letting you know.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 216 bytes

```
@echo off
set/pt=
set/an=2,e=4,s=8,w=16,r=0
:l
set/ar^|=%t:~0,1%
set t=%t:~1%
if not "%t%"=="" goto l
set/a"o=449778192>>r&3,l=1053417876>>r&3"
if %l%==0 (echo stuck)else set t=NESWNE&call echo %%t:~%o%,%l%%%
```

Simple port of my JavaScript answer. Takes input on STDIN in upper or lower case.